# Seeking helps in explanation of syntax for var[x[n]]

Tags: c++, syntax

How does the below syntax work?

```
class Solution {

    public:

        int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
            const int n = s.length();
            int ans = 0; // Set a variable as the answer;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                vector <int> seen(128);
                int j = i;
                while(j < n && !seen[s[j]]) <---- Here
                    seen[s[j++]] = 1;       <---- Here

                ans = max(ans, j - i);      <---- Here
            }
            return ans;
        }
};
```

What does the syntax `!seen[s[j]]` mean?
And the same for `seen[s[j++]]=1`.

Also, why can `i` be subtracted by `j`?

Comment: Do you understand `s[j]`? Maybe, you struggle with the fact that it returns a `char`. Keep in mind that a `char` is an integral type like an `int` (but only smaller). As it's keyword is somehow misleading, there is an alias `std::int8_t` for it (to give an option to express the intention more clearly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1**

```
s[j]
```

The above means the element at index `j` of the string named `s`.

**Case 2**

```
seen[s[j]]
```

The above means the element at index `s[j]` of variable named `seen`.

**Case 3**

```
seen[s[j++]] = 1;
```

For the above you have to know about the post-increment operator. So let’s say we have:

```
int var = 0;
std::cout << var++ <<std::end; // This will print 0
```

The  `++` in `var++` means we are incrementing the value of `var` by 1, so that it now becomes 1, but `var++` returns the old value of the variable `var` which is why we get 0 as the output.

Now let’s come back to:

```
seen[s[j++]]=1;
```

The above means the element at index `s[j++]` of the variable named `seen`. But note `j++` will do two things: **First** it will increment `j` by 1 and **second** it will return the old value of `j`. So `s[j++]` essentially means the element at index `j` of the string named `s` meanwhile the value of `j` is also incremented by 1. Thus as a whole, you're assigning a value of 1 to the element at index `s[j]` of the variable named `seen` meanwhile also increment the value of `j` by one.

> Why can `i` be subtracted by `j`?

This is because the value of `j` is incremented by 1 inside the *while* loop.

Answer (score -1):

`s[j]` is the character at index `j` in the `std::string s`. `seen[s[j]]` is the element at index `s[j]` in the `std::vector<int> seen`.

If `seen[s[j]]` is `0`, `seen[s[j]]` will return `false`, so `!seen[s[j]]` will return `true`. If `seen[s[j]]` is a nonzero value,  `seen[s[j]]` will return `true`, so `!seen[s[j]]` will return `false`.

`seen[s[j++]]=1;` set the value of `seen[s[j]]` to `1`, then increment `j`

`ans = std::max(ans, j - i);`, `std::max(ans, j - i)` will return the bigger value between `ans`, and `j - i`, then assign that value to `ans`